# Suitable filesystem for heavily fragmented files

Tags: filesystems, sparse-files

I often do data recovery jobs using `ddrescue` or similar programs. The disk image is written sparsely, because often only parts of the disk is being imaged (using `ddrescue` domain files and the like). However, on a heavily damaged disk, `ddrescue` will skip hundreds of times, leading to a file with many fragments.

Until now I've been using an NTFS filesystem for storing the images, but I find that after heavy fragmentation the writes get bogged down (I believe NTFS rewrites the *entire* fragment metadata every time a new fragment is added).

Among the Linux filesystems is there one more optimized for fragmentation?

Comment: Why not recovering to raw partitions and letting ddrescue writing the control files in the local directory?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Often I *want* a sparse file - if the disk is not too damaged, and I'm only recovering certain parts of the filesystem. I won't know about the damage until much of the way through the recovery, and then my only solution is to 'inflate' the file by copying it with `dd`.

Comment: I've since discovered that I can use `ntfsfallocate` from the ntfsutils collection to inflate the file in place. However, a better filesystem is still preferred.

Comment: While not an fs recommendation; can't you use dd to truncate the "empty" blocks? Rather than pad them all in an equal, chosen block length? Wouldn't that eliminate the "slack"?

Comment: @somebody Do you mean to writes 0's to the file 'holes' - that's the equivalent of inflating the file using `ntfsallocate`. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @afuna No. Actually the opposite. :) Speaking from use on a BSD system. dd (and ddrescue) provide the ability to pad the recovery scans to form same-size sectors. This permits one to  recreate the drive. But leaves holes in the recreated image, where the seeks were unable to obtain data. The "holes" are filled with 0's so as to truncate the data on even (sized) blocks that would otherwise form a sector (block). I was suggesting to that one might *eliminate* those 0's in an effort to reduce the size of the recovery image. But given that one needs to maintain correct sector sizes. The would only

Comment: allow the elimination of 0's in the *empty* sectors. Or more simply; removing the empty sectors from the image.

Comment: @somebody Sorry, I'm not uderstanding you. `ddrescue` is already eliminating the holes - by using a sparse file, giving a smaller image size. The problem is that when there are hundreds of (non-resident/sparse) holes the file metadata has to track all of those holes and any new allocations force the rewriting of all metadata.